# Python ctypes program works on 3.2 but incompatiable on 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, python-3.4, python-3.2

I have a program that tokenizes Thai text calling the libtahi C library.
This programs works OK with python 3.2 but fails with python3.4.
Any idea why that fails on 3.4?

Please find below the program code and outputs with both version of python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# apt-get install libthai0 libthai-doc libthai-dev libthai-data
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library

THAI_LIBRARY = find_library('thai')
if not THAI_LIBRARY:
    raise OSError('Cannot find libthai in the system')

thai = cdll.LoadLibrary(THAI_LIBRARY)

thai.th_wbrk_line.restype = c_int
thai.th_wbrk_line.argtypes = [c_wchar_p,c_wchar_p,c_size_t,c_wchar_p]

def whitespace(ain):
    # expects bytes
    ain=ain.decode('utf8')
    aout=whitespace_string(ain)
    return aout.encode('utf8')

def whitespace_string(ain):
    # expects a string
    # ain='แล้วพบกันใหม่'
    aout=' '*(2*len(ain)+1) 
    # we assume that the maximum length is a set of one character + white space
    adelim=' '
    asize=len(aout)
    res=thai.th_wbrk_line(ain,aout,asize,adelim)
    result=aout[:res]
    return result

"""
แล้วพบกันใหม่ means 'See you later.'

and is compound by three words:

แล้ว
พบกัน
ใหม่
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ain='แล้วพบกันใหม่'
    aout=whitespace_string(ain)
    print(ain,'=>',aout)
    aout=whitespace(ain.encode('utf8'))
    print(aout.decode('utf8'))
```

The outputs are:
with python3.2 tokenization happens:

```
python3.2 thai_libthai.py 
แล้วพบกันใหม่ => แล้ว พบ กัน ใหม่
แล้ว พบ กัน ใหม่
```

with python3.4 the result string is blank:

```
python3.4 thai_libthai.py 
แล้วพบกันใหม่ =>
```

Comment: You can't pass a Python string as an output buffer. Use `aout = (c_wchar * (2 * len(ain) + 1))()` or `aout = create_unicode_buffer(2 * len(ain) + 1)`.

Comment: In this case it's working in Python 3.2 because ctypes uses the `PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE` macro to directly pass the underlying `wchar_t *` buffer used by the object. That can't be used in 3.3+ since the underlying string representation was [completely redesigned](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393). Now it calls `PyUnicode_AsWideCharString` to create a temporary `wchar_t` buffer that's kept alive for the call by referencing a `capsule` in the temporary `CArgObject`.

Comment: 3.4.3 source links: [`c_wchar_p_from_param`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.4.3/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l1470) and [`Z_set`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.4.3/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1374).

Comment: Hello eryksun ! Using `aout = (c_wchar * (2 * len(ain) + 1))()` makes the code **work** on both python 3.2 and 3.4. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `aout = (c_wchar * (2 * len(ain) + 1))()` makes the code work on both python 3.2 and 3.4. Thank you to eryksun!